# what difference bettween /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/ && /sys/fs/cgroup/xxx/

Tags: systemd

I know that [./systemd-219/src/core/mount-setup.c](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v219/src/core/mount-setup.c)  define some cgroup mount path .

But I do not know why systemd create directory  /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/ and what's difference between  /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/ and /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/?

Is /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/ mount path just mean default cgroup path?

```
#ll /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Jul  6  2017 cgroup.clone_children
--w--w--w-  1 root root 0 Jul  6  2017 cgroup.event_control
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Jul  6 15:24 cgroup.procs
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Jul  6  2017 cgroup.sane_behavior
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 0 Jul  6 15:23 docker.slice
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Jul  6  2017 notify_on_release
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Jul  6  2017 release_agent
drwxr-xr-x 65 root root 0 Jul  6 15:38 system.slice
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Jul  6  2017 tasks
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 0 Jul  6 21:18 user.slice
```

Answer (score 3):

Systemd 219 uses the Linux kernel [cgroup v1](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt) feature and mounts multiple hierarchies under `/sys/fs/cgroup`, some for controllers, some without.

`/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd` is a hierarchy without croup controllers, just for systemd usage (tracking which processes are part of which cgroups).

This will change once the migration to [cgroup v2](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt) is complete and there will be only one cgroup hierarchy (unified hierarchy).

Comment: But even with `cgroup_no_v1=all` system `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd` still exist.

Comment: If you want systemd to only use the new v2 hierarchy, you should set [systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html#systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy) to true on the kernel command line. Those options may differ depending on your systemd version.